# How can I recover a file in shell?

Tags: shell, terminal, backup, recover

I had a file named "ex1.f95" in my shell, and wanted to change all the "y_parameter" for "y". Therefore, I used:

sed "s/y_parameter/y/g" > ex1.f95

When I opened the file, everything was deleted! There was nothing written.

Is there a way I can recover everything I had inside?

Comment: You should have done `sed -i "s/y_parameter/y/g" ex1.f95`. Recovering a file in linux is (sometimes) possible, but it is not a simple task. If lost file is *really* important, maybe you should try to google it and ask on superuser.com if you have specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to substitute with sed is `sed 's/pattern_1/pattern_2/g' file_name`. If you want the changes to be saved you have to use `sed -i`, which is better than redirecting the standard output. Here, since you don't give any input to sed, it outputs nothing to the standard output and then you redirect it to your file, so you end up with an empty file.

I am afraid the file is definitely lost if you rewrite it by redirecting the standard output in it, but it is worth googling it.